# Specify request method with urllib2?

Tags: python, post, get, request, urllib2

This code produces a POST request:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://somedomain.com/", data)
```

I would like to produce a GET request - any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://somedomain.com/?" + data)
```

[edited]

If you want to send xml/json/etc data in the body, use something like:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://somedomain.com/?" + parameters, data)
```

This will use the POST method, but any "GET" parameters will also be available to your application.

Comment: What if I need to include a body in my request?

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to include a body when using the GET method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you also use `requests` that has a more explicit API:

- [Make a GET request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-get-request):

  ```
  r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
  ```
- [Make a POST request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request):

  ```
  r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
  ```